# Get country name from E164 phone number format

Tags: java

I have the following two Strings

```
String e164;        // E164 Number Format
String countryCode; // E.g. '+1' for US
```

Is there a way to get ISO country code from one of these Strings? My goal is to get the `Country name` from these and the solution I have in mind requires ISO code first, which is the following:

```
Locale l = new Locale("", isoCode);
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry(), isoCode);
```

Maybe there is a more elegant solution to this that does not require ISO code?

Answer (score 0):

Google's LibPhonenumber provide offline and free DB. Just use `PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder` in their library. I think this will work fine if you just look for a Country from the number

But if you want, up-to-date information you better use online lookup provider like Twilio.